# android cross activity interfaces

Tags: android, android-activity

Say I have two active activities, `A` (has a window) and `B` (has a view embedded in `A`, but is still it's own activity).
The activities are in different packages but running in the same process.

A view in activity `B` is added to a view in `A` that implements an interface `I`. The declaration of `I` is in a library shared between `A` and `B`.

So I would assume that I could do something along the lines of this inside of an instance of `B`:

```
viewInA = viewInB.getParent();
(I)viewInA;
```

But I get a casting error. Is there a way to make this work?

Doing a bit of introspection can easily prove that `viewInA` does in fact implement `I`. The package that `I` resides in is, of course, the same for both activities.

My set of restrictions due to the situation is rather unique; Doing simple message passing with intents won't work.

I could create a wrapper that uses introspection to get the Methods on the view that I know exist. But that's ugly and I'm lazy.

Comment: Why are you doing what you have described in your first paragraph?

Comment: "B (has a view embedded in A, but is still it's own activity)" I am unsure what you mean by this... Also, how can you have two active activities?

Answer (score 0):

Everything else aside, if you get a casting error in Java, it's because viewInA does in fact not implement I. Be aware that getParent() returns a class implementing ViewParent... (i.e. does I extend ViewParent??)

Nonetheless, you can set a breakpoint, and check at runtime what type viewInA has!